# Bitwise Assignment Operator for Boolean instead of Longer Expression ( |= operator)

Tags: javascript, boolean, bit-manipulation

### Question

A friend of mine is asking whether he could use:

```
result |= condition
```

Instead of:

```
result = result || condition
```

in javascript, for boolean operations.

I'm well aware that one is bitwise and the other is logical. 
However, what would be the effect on boolean variables?

I'm not currently in front of my computer but also wondering if there could be such a thing as a `||`= operator.

### Update

I just realized that a `boolean` value is essentialy a `1 bit value`. Does this mean that for `booleans` the `logical or` has the same as the `bitewise or` ?

So `a|=b` would be equivalent to `a=a|b` ?

Comment: It all depends on the possible values of `result` and `condition`. `"foo" || 42` and `"foo" | 42` produce very different results.

Comment: Agreed with @FelixKling - need more information on what you are doing. Bitwise and logical OR are pretty different.

Comment: Yep, works fine on booleans since they are converted to `1` and `0` respectively. However, the result is will be a number instead of a Boolean, which might matter.

Comment: @Felix Kling Thanks... it's not immediately obvious sometimes when your tired :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean that for booleans the logical or has the same as the bitewise or ?

In your case, somewhat.

When using logical expressions, operands may either be true-ish or false-ish. An OR-expression here returns the first one that is true-ish (not necessarily the boolean `true`), or if none is, the last operand.

```
result || condition
```

Returns `result` if `result` is true-ish, otherwise `condition`

When using bitwise expressions, operands are signed 32 bit integers. If you limit that to one bit, this somewhat resembles the behaviour of logical expressions: If one bit is set, an OR-expression returns 1.

```
result | condition
```

Returns a signed 32 bit integer with a value of 0 or 1 for operands convertible to a 32bit integer with only the least significant bit used.

However, when using bitwise expressions on operands that are not a 32 bit integer, implicit conversions to 32 bit integers have to be performed and there might be additional edge cases. I'd not recommend using bitwise expressions for logical operands.